# Microsoft Teams Tab application can't access clipboard

Tags: iframe, microsoft-teams

I'm developing the Microsoft Teams Tab application.
Tab application is run inside Microsoft Teams through iframe, so there are different iframe restrictions.
Actually I'm facing the issue user unable to use the clipboard-write feature.
[image]

It's possible to make it work with specifying parameters https://web.dev/async-clipboard/#permissions-policy-integration

Is there any Manifest or context option to specify iframe parameters?

Comment: Hi @Dmytro Yaroshenko, I'm able to repro this issue from our end and taking this for internal discussion with team and will update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Manifest or context option to specify iframe parameters. Instead you can use text/input field to overcome this issue.

Comment: Could you kindly provide more information? How do you use text/input field to overcome this issue (clipboard blocked in iframe)? Found the same on uservoice here: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/43055961-allow-clipboard-api-access-on-custom-teams-apps

Comment: Also stuck on this - any updates?