# How can I get clipboard permission in Teams add-on app

Tags: permissions, microsoft-teams, clipboard

I'm developing a plugin in Teams
I use clipboard in this plugin, but when I do Clipboard operation, it gives the following error.
There is no clipboard permission in the device permissions section of Teams.
how can i solve this problem

Error Message=Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes for more details.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this permission is not implemented in teams (means: your teams app cannot use the clipboard API). If all you need is to allow user copying some text on the screen to the clipboard, you could go for a workaround to use "old" API, i.e.

```
<TextField ... onFocus={event => event.target.select()} >
....
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Related question:
[Microsoft Teams Tab application can't access clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598347/microsoft-teams-tab-application-cant-access-clipboard)